# Divs not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, alignment, gallery

I've been away for ages and I'm beginning my first build for years. This is probably something that wouldn't have been an issue before several years of coding rust!: I think it's a pretty basic problem, but it's driving me nuts.

I've built two containers. Container1 (the red one) is to have an image in it and adjusts nicely to 70% of the display.

Container2 (the green one) is for the caption etc, but I can't get it to sit under Container1. It's currently stuck firm at the top on the page.

Any help with this would be massively appreciated.

```css
#container1 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 136px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #c9c9c9;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container1">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" align="center" />
  </div>

  <div id="container2">
    CAPTION INFO TO GO HERE
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make container two display block instead of inline-block and give a try

Comment: You might also check out the `<figure>` tag. It incorporates room for both an image and a caption by default. And yes, loose the absolute/relative positioning, there is no need for.

Answer (score 1):

As you have put **position: absolute** in your **#container1**, it does not follow the normal layout of the page while **position: relative** means that **#container2** will behave just like the default, **position: static** until you specify some kind of top, left, right or bottom.

So one way to fix this is by removing the absolute and relative positioning. Keep the flow of the document as is. It will be much easier.

Here's a [link to an excellent tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) to revise your positioning concepts. It helped me a lot.

I have attached a simplified version of the relevant code. Check it out.

```css
#container1 {
width: 70%;
height: 170px;
margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
background-color: red ;
}


#container2 {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: green ;
}


img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;  
margin: 0 auto;
border: 4px solid #ffffff;
border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #c9c9c9;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image"  style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" 
align="center" />
</div>

<div id="container2">
CAPTION INFO TO GO HERE
</div>
```